# parsing JSON file using telegraf input plugin : unexpected Output

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I’m new to telegraf and influxdb, and currently looking forward to exploring telegraf, but unfortunetly, I have some difficulty getting started, I will try to explain my problem below:

**Objectif: parsing JSON file using telegraf input plugin.**

**Input :**   https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0abf7c609d000a7c9300dc20ee0f565120200624164841/ab22bf ( JSON file used )
The input json file is a repetition of the same structure that starts from params and ends at it.

you find below the main part of the input file :

```
{
   "events":[
      {
         "params":[
            {
               "name":"element_type",
               "value":"Home_Menu"
            },
            {
               "name":"element_id",
               "value":""
            },
            {
               "name":"uuid",
               "value":"981CD435-E6BC-01E6-4FDC-B57B5CFA9824"
            },
            {
               "name":"section_label",
               "value":"HOME"
            },
            {
               "name":"element_label",
               "value":""
            }
         ],
         "libVersion":"4.2.5",
         "context":{
            "locale":"ro-RO",
            "country":"RO",
            "application_name":"spresso",
            "application_version":"2.1.8",
            "model":"iPhone11,8",
            "os_version":"13.5",
            "platform":"iOS",
            "application_lang_market":"ro_RO",
            "platform_width":"320",
            "device_type":"mobile",
            "platform_height":"480"
         },
         "date":"2020-05-31T09:38:55.087+03:00",
         "ssid":"spresso",
         "type":"MOBILEPAGELOAD",
         "user":{
            "anonymousid":"6BC6DC89-EEDA-4EB6-B6AD-A213A65941AF",
            "userid":"2398839"
         },
         "reception_date":"2020-06-01T03:02:49.613Z",
         "event_version":"v1"
      }
```

**Issue :** Following the documentation, I tried to define a simple telegraf.conf file as below:

```
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
…  
  [[inputs.file]]
  files = ["/home/mouhcine/json/file.json"]
  json_name_key = "My_json"
 #... Listing all the string fields in the json.(I put only these for simplicity reason).
  json_string_fields = ["ssid","type","userid","name","value","country","model"]
  data_format = "json"
  json_query= "events"
```

Basically declaring string fields in the telegraf.conf file would do it, but I couldn’t get all the fields that are subset in the json file, like for example what’s inside **( params or context )**.
So finally, I get to parse fields with the same level of hierarchy as **ssid, type, libVersion,** but not the ones inside **( params, context, user).**

**Output : Screen2 ( attachment ).**
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxRW4.png)

By curiosity, I tried to test the documentation’s example, in order to verify whether I get the same expected result, and the answer is no :/, I don’t get to parse the string field in the subset of the file.

The doc’s example below:

```
 Input :
{
   "a": 5,
   "b": {
       "c": 6,
       "my_field": "description"
   },
   "my_tag_1": "foo",
   "name": "my_json"
}
telegraf.conf
 [[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
… 
 [[inputs.file]]
 files = ["/home/mouhcine/json/influx.json"]
 json_name_key = "name"
 tag_keys = ["my_tag_1"]
 json_string_fields = ["my_field"]
 data_format = "json"
```

Expected Output : `my_json,my_tag_1=foo a=5,b_c=6,my_field="description"`

The Result I get :  "my_field" is missing.
**Output: Screen 1 ( attachement ).**
[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nh2LK.png)

By the way, I use the influxdb cloud 2, and I apologize for the long description of this little problem, I would appreciate some help please :), Thank you so much in advance.